# How to get an SGE job state

Tags: cluster-computing, sungridengine

This may be a very simple question, but if I have the job ID, how would I get the state of the job submitted through SGE? I basically want to check on a job ID and see if it's in an error state, it's still running, or it's completed.

I was thinking of something like this

```
qstat -u '*' | grep 123456
```

But if the job ID is low, it may return lines other than the one that I want. And using a command like this...

```
qstat -j '123456'
```

...doesn't seem to return the job state.

Answer (score 1):

Issue the command:

```
qstat -xml
```

The results will be in XML format.  You can parse the result and extract the state:

```
<job_list state="pending">
  <JB_job_number>3150728</JB_job_number>
  <JAT_prio>0.00000</JAT_prio>
  <JB_name>snpReference</JB_name>
  <JB_owner>me</JB_owner>
  <state>hqw</state>
  <JB_submission_time>2016-11-23T11:54:01</JB_submission_time>
  <queue_name></queue_name>
  <jclass_name></jclass_name>
  <slots>1</slots>
</job_list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have migrated to Torque/Maui so solution may not be exact for GridEngine.

For using `qstat` and `grep` try word-based search:

```
qstat -u '*' | grep -w 123456
```

Or, use `awk`

```
qstat -u '*' | awk '$1 == 123456 { print }'
```

For Toque/Maui I can get the job state using `qstat -f $jobid`:

```
qstat -f 123456 | grep job_state
```

Maybe you can do similar with the `-j` option:

```
qstat -j $job_id | grep job_state
```

Comment: The -f option doesn't seem to work. It gives an error that the jobID is an invalid option. It works fine as `qstat -j` though. I'm using SGE 8.1.8

Comment: Indeed. I changed this back to use the `-j` option.

Comment: Seems for my version of qstat, it doesn't return the `job_state` value when using the `-j` option.

Comment: Can you post example output please. Also, you can change output format using different flags. See OUTPUT FORMATS section of http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qstat.html.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your regex more specific:

```
qstat | grep "^123456\s"
```

That way you'll only get jobs whose whole job number is the one you specify.